# assembly 8086 - how can i turn on the direction flag?

Tags: assembly, flags, dosbox

Im using dosbox to program in 16bit assembly language..

```
mov df,1
```

i know this does not work but thats why im asking the question

i want to know if we can change its value by desire.

maybe it is assigned generally like

```
mov flagreg,1000011010000110b
```

if there are any mistakes in the question or what im saying feel free to correct me!

***EDITED:***

what im trying to do here is to inversely print a string

> ```
> .data
> st1 db '1111$0000'
> .code
>
> main proc
> mov ax,@data
> mov ds,ax
>
> pushf
> pop ax
> or ax,0400h
> push ax
> popf
>
> std
> mov ah,9
> mov dx,offset st1
> int 21h
>
> mov ah,4ch
> int 21h
> main endp
>
> end main
> ```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

0000

**ACTUAL OUTPUT:**

1111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the direction flag with the `std` (set direction flag) instruction and clear it with the `cld` (clear direction flag) instruction.

The direction flag is bit 10 in the flags register.  You can also manipulate it by directly changing the flags register.  For example, to set the direction flag, you could do:

```
pushf         ; push flags onto the stack
pop ax        ; pop flags into ax
or ax, 0400h  ; set direction flag
push ax       ; push ax
popf          ; pop into flags
```

Comment: please check my upadated question

Comment: @HassaanRaza I think you misunderstood the purpose of the direction flag.  The direction flag only affects the operation of the string instructions `lods`, `scas`, `movs`, and `cmps`.  It does not affect DOS calls.  If you want to print a string in reverse, you have to reverse it yourself.  The direction flag does not help you with that.